# Is this good practice for inserting contents of a CSV file in database using Django?

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm trying to insert a list of elements into a table. The input comes from a CSV file, and some of the entries may be erroneous. Is the following good practice? ( All of it is pseudocode )

```
for line in lines:
  my_obj_entries = parse_line(line)
  obj = Entry(name=my_obj_entries[0], value=my_obj_entries[1])
  try: 
    obj.clean()
    obj.save()
  except ValidationError:
    print "Invalid object for line %s" % line
```

I'm coming from Rails, and this seems like the way to insert data, while still checking for validity.

Comment: How would you deal with duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation to data in Django is made by forms. You should use forms to validate your data and then save it using form's save method. See [django documentation on forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/); it is really easy to create forms that validate a model you have created.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry

for line in lines:
    data = parse_line(line)
    form = EntryForm(data)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    else:
        print("form not valid: %s" % form.errors)
```

Comment: I have a scheduled task that is responsible of inserting.

Comment: Does scheduled task matter here? Can you elaborate on this? I'm adding some code now.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you! Would the same be applicable for a relation? What if for example, these Entry models belong to a Catalogue. How could this be? `c = Catalogue.objects.get(pk=some_id)` I'm particularly interested in validating this: `c.entry_set.create(...)`

Comment: If you have the relation from CSV, I think you'll validate it by using its own form. If it is from an existing object from DB then it is already validated. If there's a custom constraint on the relation then you should define it on the form and raise a ValidationError yourself. This page should be of help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/